# What changes is Mocha waiting for...?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am running a set of tests, and mocha runs the tests the first time I run it, but then it says:

```
ℹ [mocha] waiting for changes...
```

but it waits forever. No changes I make cause it to rerun my tests.

The test itself is a chai test, run with mocha. Everything is in Typescript

I am running the tests as follows:

```
  "scripts": {
    "tests": "mocha --require ts-node/register --watch --watch-extensions ts ./*.spec.ts"
  }
```

I've changed both the test files and the implementation files, and nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--watch-extensions` is probably no more. See current options : https://mochajs.org/#command-line-usage. Use `--extensions`.

Note: At some point `--watch-extensions` was deprecated

Comment: Alas, removing that doesnt appear to help.  I how have "test-watch": "mocha --require ts-node/register --watch ./*.spec.ts", and it still waits forever no matter what I do.

Comment: Don't just remove. Also add `--extensions ts,tsx` 